# How to find the relation of these two functions, when we are considering the time complexity?

Tags: algorithm

For example, like the question below, can I solve this question by just doing the limit comparison test?

Let f(n) = n · (4^n) and let g(n) = 2^(3n)

which relation best applies:

f(n) ≤ O(g(n)), f(n) ≥ Ω(g(n)), or f(n) = Θ(g(n))?

Comment: you can plot the two functions, and then see for yourself, if you understand your complexities:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e9izepoxsc

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the limit tests are actually the definition of this notation.
For the provided example |f(n)|/g(n) is n*2<sup>-n</sup>, so f(n)=O(g(n)) is true, but f(n) = Ω(g(n)), and, therefore, f(n) = Θ(g(n)) is false.

Answer (score 0):

As we know `2^(3n) = 8^n`:

```
lim_{n \to \infty} (f(n)/g(n) = n * 4^n / 8^n = n/2^n)
```

As the growth of `2^n` is faster than `n`, the above limit is zero. Hence, `f(n) = o(g(n))` (little-oh).